# setting variable to avoid function execution

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 Elements image and div overlapping each other,when I click on div it calls  transitIT()  which rotates div but again if I do next click too fast then image clicked is called I don't understand how, I tried using `event.stopPropagation()` and setting  clickedEnabled to avoid image click but image click event  is getting called.

```
$(document).on('click', '#front', function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
//alert('Front Clicked globe='+globe);
 transitIT(this);
 });


 $(document).on('click', 'img', function() {
  alert('htmlcalled image Clicked Called='+clickEnabled);

/*to check if div is transitioning state*/
    if (!clickEnabled){return;}

    //Doing some alignement for image               ...........

     });
```

Comment: Is the `img` inside the `#front`?

Comment: can you share the html to show the relationship btw these two

Comment: @Arun P Johny , front div and images are inside #myimageflow div ..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to test the element id, because you don't know in which order both callbacks will be actually called.

```
  $(document).on('click', 'img', function() {
    if (this.id !== "front")
    {
      alert('htmlcalled image Clicked Called='+clickEnabled);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to prevent the event bubbling:

```
$(document).on('click', 'img', function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName !== 'IMG') return;

    alert('htmlcalled image Clicked Called=' + clickEnabled);
    //Doing some alignement for image ...........
});
```

Comment: will it stop event ocuur for each time ?? i mean if i will click on image then function will run or not?

Comment: @ Palash Mondal is there any code which will disable img click event ..div click {//write some code to diable image click}

Comment: Sorry @simmisimmi, I didn't got you on this _which will disable img click event ..div click_

Comment: @ Palash Mondal $(#front).click(){// disable image click listener}

Comment: @simmisimmi: `$(document).on('click', '#front', function (event) {
    if (e.target !== this) return;
    // Your code here..
});`